# Решение интеграла методом средних прямоугольников.Как определить на сколько частей разбивать?

Tags: java, математика

Написал код ,решающий интеграл методом средних прямоугольников.Но как сделать так,что бы пользователь вводил точность и программа автоматически определяла на сколько кусков надо разбить интеграл?

```
 public class Main
 {

static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
static double f(double x)
{
    return(1/x);
}
static double integralpram(int a,int b,int n)
{
    double s=0;
    double h=(b-a)*1.0/n;
    for (double x=a+h/2;x<b;x=x+h)
    {
        s=s+f(x)*h;
    }

    return s;
}
public static void main(String args[ ])
{

    double  y;
    int a,b;
    System.out.println(" F(x)=1/x");

        System.out.println("Введите диапазон интегрирования");
        a = scanner.nextInt();
        b = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();


    y=integralpram(a,b,100);
    System.out.println(y);
}}
```

Comment: Уменьшаешь шаг, пока разница между предыдущей и последующей итерациями не станет меньше заданного значения.

Comment: Только при уменьшении шага - например, вдвое - подумайте, как использовать результаты предыдущего просчета, чтобы не выполнять одну и ту же работу 2, 3 и так далее раз :)

Answer (score 1):

Для первого приближения можно оценить погрешность метода аналитически, однако для этого придётся оценивать вторую производную на каждом промежутке

```
d = Max(f'') * (b-a)^3 / (24 * n^2)
```

На практике можно увеличивать число интервалов, сравнивать прошлое и текущее значение интеграла, и остановиться, когда модуль разницы  становиться менее заданной погрешности

Comment: Как найти производную любой функции в java?Есть какая то библиотека?

Comment: Наверное, есть но найти можно и численно `f''(i) = (f(i-1) + f(i+1)-2f(i))/h^2`